# Java Process Builder, program process starts but the program does not use CPU or Memory

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, processbuilder

Hello and thanks in advance,
I have the following problem: I have a GUI and with a button I need to launch a c++ program that is on the same machine. This program uses a particular framework called SSM (ROS like) for sharing data. **The program itself works fine when started from terminal** but when I start it with java process builder I cannot access to any data but I can still see the process running.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and OpenJDK7. The code that I'm using is the following (**Updated according to the comment**):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);    
builder.start();
```

where command comes from some data that I receive via UDP:

```
command[0] = Main_gui.getHomePath()+"PFforAEV_autoCalib_20140418/PFforAEV0.2.2";
command[1] = String.valueOf(initialPosition[0]);
command[2] = String.valueOf(initialPosition[1]);
command[3] = String.valueOf(initialPosition[2]);
command[4] = "walllandmark_F41_20130125";
```

To be more specific the process **PFforAEV0.2.2** is there, running, but it seems that it does not use any CPU or memory. I can't access the data via the framework. Looks like if it is just hanging.

If you need more detail just ask.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you read its output stream? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: I tried the solution below from @rafalopez79.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read from the InputStream of the stdout and stderr of the child process, or redirect them to the streams of the parent process:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.start();
```

See this [example](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/java-fundamentals/blob/master/process/src/main/java/slides/ExamplesOnSlidesProcess.java)

Comment: I tried your solution but it isn't working. Still no CPU and no information, if I'm not wrong redirecting the Output and the Error as you suggested just let the output of my process go to the parent right? In that case do I need to do anything else to manage the output and don't get stuck (I don't care about the output btw)?

Comment: What I did and now with the output in a text file (as your link suggest) it's working. Thank you.